# Send objects over TCP with multiple clients and one server

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

Okay, I've been looking around and have found tutorials on both sending custom objects over TCP and also connecting multiple clients to one server, however I haven't been able to find an example of both so have decided to try it myself however I'm stuck. I so far have written a server that can handle an unlimited number of clients but have failed to implement sending of objects. This is the code I have so far for sending custom objects:

Client code:

```
            Person p = new Person("Tyler", "Durden", 30); // create my serializable object
            string serverIp = "127.0.0.1";

            TcpClient client = new TcpClient(serverIp, 9050); // have my connection established with a Tcp Server

            IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); // the formatter that will serialize my object on my stream

            NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream(); // the stream
            formatter.Serialize(strm, p); // the serialization process

            strm.Close();
            client.Close();
```

Server code:

```
        TcpListener server = new TcpListener(9050);
        server.Start();
        TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream strm = client.GetStream();
        IFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        Person p = (Person)formatter.Deserialize(strm); // you have to cast the deserialized object

        strm.Close();
        client.Close();
        server.Stop();
```

This is the code I currently have for multiple clients:

Server code:

```
private ArrayList m_aryClients = new ArrayList(); //List of connected clients (Used for threading)

    public Program()
    {
        //Empty constructor
    }

    static Program()
    {
    }

    #region Main Enty Point
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        //Set log file location
        setLogFileLocation("/usr/local/bin/ClipCloud/" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() + ".log");
        //Start the application
        printAndLog("Starting server");
        Program appmain = new Program();
        //Get local hostname
        IPAddress[] addressList = null;
        string hostName = "";
        try
        {
            hostName = Dns.GetHostName();
            addressList = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            printAndLog("Failed to get local address (" + ex.Message + ")", 1);
        }
        //Start listening and set up threads
        if ((addressList == null ? false : (int)addressList.Length >= 1))
        {
            object[] objArray = new object[] { "Listening on : (", hostName, ") ", addressList[0], ",", 399 };
            printAndLog(string.Concat(objArray), 0);
            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            socket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(addressList[0], 399));
            socket.Listen(10);
            socket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(appmain.OnConnectRequest), socket);
            //Wait until user types exit
            while (!(Console.ReadLine().ToLower() == "exit"))
            {}
            printAndLog("Shutting down server");
            socket.Close();
            //Clean up after yourself
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            printAndLog("Application successfully shutdown");
        }
        else
        {
            printAndLog("Unable to obtain local address" , 2);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Server requests
    public void NewConnection(Socket sockClient)
    {
        //new client connected
        ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(sockClient);
        m_aryClients.Add(clientHandler);
        printAndLog(string.Concat("Client (",clientHandler.Sock.RemoteEndPoint, ") connected"));
        //Send client welcome message
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        string str = string.Concat("{", now.ToString("G"), "}");
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToCharArray());
        clientHandler.Sock.Send(bytes, (int)bytes.Length, SocketFlags.None);
        clientHandler.SetupRecieveCallback(this);
    }

    public void OnConnectRequest(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket asyncState = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
            NewConnection(asyncState.EndAccept(ar));
            asyncState.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnConnectRequest), asyncState);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            printAndLog(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    public void OnRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        ClientHandler asyncState = (ClientHandler)ar.AsyncState;
        byte[] recievedData = asyncState.GetRecievedData(ar);
        if ((int)recievedData.Length >= 1)
        {
            foreach (ClientHandler mAryClient in this.m_aryClients)
            {
                try
                {
                    //This is where all data is sent out to all users!
                    mAryClient.Sock.Send(recievedData);
                }
                catch
                {
                    printAndLog(string.Concat("Failed to send data to client (", asyncState.Sock.RemoteEndPoint, ")"), 2);
                    mAryClient.Sock.Close();
                    this.m_aryClients.Remove(asyncState);
                    return;
                }
            }
            asyncState.SetupRecieveCallback(this);
        }
        else
        {
            printAndLog(string.Concat("Client (", asyncState.Sock.RemoteEndPoint, ") disconnected"), 0);
            asyncState.Sock.Close();
            this.m_aryClients.Remove(asyncState);
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
    internal class ClientHandler
{
    private Socket m_sock;

    private byte[] m_byBuff = new byte[50];

    public Socket Sock
    {
        get
        {
            return this.m_sock;
        }
    }

    public ClientHandler(Socket sock)
    {
        this.m_sock = sock;
    }

    public byte[] GetRecievedData(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        int num = 0;
        try
        {
            num = this.m_sock.EndReceive(ar);
        }
        catch
        {
        }
        byte[] numArray = new byte[num];
        Array.Copy(this.m_byBuff, numArray, num);
        return numArray;
    }

    public void SetupRecieveCallback(Program app)
    {
        try
        {
            AsyncCallback asyncCallback = new AsyncCallback(app.OnRecievedData);
            this.m_sock.BeginReceive(this.m_byBuff, 0, (int)this.m_byBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None, asyncCallback, this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Recieve callback setup failed! {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me connecting the two.

Comment: Are you getting any specific error?  Unclear what you're actually asking...

Comment: No I can't implement the two methods together. I don't know how to send objects with multiple clients and one server.

Comment: I presume you have two executables, one server one client.  You start server and it starts listening for connections, correct (that's your 3rd code block)? You then have second executable with your client code  (1st code block) that you run which tries to connect to server and send object over connection, correct?  If you're thus far, then what happens when you try to send - do you get any exceptions?  Does the server receive any bytes?  Do you get exception when it is deserializing?  If so, what are the exceptions that you're getting?

Comment: Sorry If I confussed you. To put things simply I need to know where to put the code that receives the object in the main server code, I then need to send the object out to all connected clients.